# JS replace inputted single quote to another character

Tags: javascript

I have input area where I want to replace inputted single quote ' to another character instantly. Something like this but for single quote only:

```
!(/^[A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]/ig,''):null;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just remove all the characters in your example and replace with single quote.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: please post what you have tried.

Comment: !(/^["]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[']/ig,''):null;

Comment: Just to clarify, is this what you want? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzaXWL?editors=1010

Comment: @Marat See cyberskunk's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily achieved by using `replace` function. In case you want to replace all instances of the single quote with uppercase x use
`f.value = f.value.replace(/'/g, 'X')`

You can refer to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for further details.